# Gap below CSS flipping animation

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a description after an image that flips on hover to a different image, but there's always a gap below the image. I've figured that I can add `margin-top:-200px` to the description to eliminate the gap, but I would like to know exactly what's causing it and if there's another way to solve this.

https://jsfiddle.net/vLnpkkos/

It's all very new to me, hence why this question might be ridiculously stupid. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height in the following CSS selector is causing the gap.

```
.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
}
```